# Retrofit, Gson, parse data to server from app custom jsonfile

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit2

I'am trying to work with retrofit to parse custom json data with Gson to a localhost server using a REST API.

this is the resulting json im looking for:

```
{
"user_id": 2,
"product": {
    "id": 15,
    "item_count": 99
    }
}
```

Below is interface i created

```
public interface APIService {

@POST("/products")

@FormUrlEncoded
Call<Product> savePost(@Header("Token")String authKey,
                    @Field("product") Object product,
                    @Field("userId") String userId);
}
```

here is the function im useing to send the data

```
// string that i use to call the classes

        String userID;
        String authKey;

        mAPIService = ApiUtils.getAPIService();
        mProduct = new Product();
        mProduct.setId(productID);
        mProduct.setItemCount(numberOfItems.getText().toString().trim());
        final String stringMProduct = mProduct.toString();

        sendPost(userID, stringMProduct, authKey);

// the function that parses all the data

public void sendPost( String userID, String product, String authKey ) {
    mAPIService.savePost(authKey, userID, product).enqueue(new Callback<Product>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Product> call, retrofit2.Response<Product> response) {
            if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                showResponse(response.body().toString());
                Log.i(TAG, "post submitted to API." + response.body().toString());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Product> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to submit post to API.");
        }
    });
}
```

here is the classes im using Gson to parse the data to json

```
public class OrderRequest {

     @SerializedName("product")
     @Expose
     private Product product;
     @SerializedName("user_id")
     @Expose
     private String userId;

     public Product getProduct() {
         return product;
     }

     public void setProduct(Product product) {
         this.product = product;
     }

     public String getUserId() {
         return userId;
     }

     public void setUserId(String userId) {
         this.userId = userId;
     }

     @Override

     public String toString() {
         return "OrderRequest{" +
                 "product=" + product +
                 ", userId='" + userId + '\'' +
        '}';
    }
}
```

the other Gcode class.

```
Public class Product {

    @SerializedName("item_count")
    @Expose
    private String itemCount;
    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private String id;

    public String getItemCount() {
        return itemCount;
    }

    public void setItemCount(String itemCount) {
        this.itemCount = itemCount;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Product{" +
                "itemCount='" + itemCount + '\'' +
                ", id='" + id + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

this is all the code that im useing to parse the data to the server, im realy confused how im supposed to debug it or where the payload is i know it is a code dump and that is not allowed. the bit im the mosted confusec about is making the costom post request the bit where you can have array within arrays

Comment: What exactly is your problem with this code?

Comment: The problem is that the data is not posting and i think that im doint the parsing of the data wrong, but idk how to cheak

Comment: Inside `onFailure()` method change `Log.e(TAG, "Unable to submit post to API.");` to `Log.e(TAG, t);` and try to send data from client to server. If it fails to send data, you'll get error log (reason for the failure). Just [edit] the question and post that error log here. OR test that API with Postman client and confirm.

Answer (score 0):

for arrays and other type of data you can send data inside requestBody and on server side you can easily map that to the POJO class you are creating to the POJO class, which is same as POJO class you are sending.

Comment: I'm useing a larvel backend that requres json so i dont think that this is possible :)

Comment: He is actually telling you the right thing to do. You just dont get it.

Answer (score 0):

For one, what is the url youre setting to retrofit? It seems like youre setting it something like.. "http://something.com/something". Retrofit requires that the url you use should end in "/". I could tell because your post method is "/products". Which then if you set the url correctly would be "http://something.com/something//products"

Not only that. @formURLEncoded could not be use with post methods. And with that @field would and should that also work..